# iframe height not changing when the source height changes dynamically

Tags: html, iframe, dynamic, include

I have html pages A and B.
I am including html B page in html A using iframe.

Means iframe source point to "page B".

Issue is, if the page B changes dynamically - iframe height is not changing.
How can I control this?

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is part of Page A, so its size is controlled by Page A's DOM. If you want Page B (the iframe content) to affect the size of the iframe on Page A, you can do that with a bit of Javascript, provided both Page A and Page B are on the same domain.

The javascript that would work on Page B:

```
var iframe = window.parent.getElementById("iframe-id"); // Get the iframe from the parent window
iframe.style.width = newwidth; // set its width (should be a string "##px")
iframe.style.height = newheight; // set its height (should be a string "##px")
```

Where `newwidth` and `newheight` are retrieved from whatever is dynamically changing the size of the elements on Page B.